# Probability and Variance question

Tags: probability

Can you help me solve this problem?

> *Problem*: You are playing a game, The game has 6 circles (O O O O O O)  every time you play for 1 coin, each circle has a chance to be linked to the next one with $50\%$ chance of linking or not linking. In order to win, all $6$ circles have to be linked. (O-O-O-O-O-O)

What is the chance of you winning each time you play this game and what is the variance?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 0):

From one newb to the next...  I haven't spent too much time looking at this and don't intend to at the moment, but...   let me throw out a few ideas.

let x = number of plays.

1. P(x < 5) = 0.  The first 4 plays just link at most 4 of the circles.
2. You also have to consider that a coin might land on two circles that are already linked.
3. Winning when p = 5 is the luckiest, i.e. the smallest probability.  The way to win for (p = 5) is that each toss lands on an "unlinked" link.
4. .5 is only going to be your success probability for all tosses in which there are no links.  Once you have one linked, the probability of success goes down since landing on a "linked" link is no longer a success.

Try drawing a tree diagram.  It's going to have lots of branches.  I would also suggest starting with an easier problem, say 3 circles.